# Reset Facebook Token Reference - Facebook SDK 4.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.0

I previously used the following to clear and reset the Facebook access token

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

Since the update to 4.0 this no longer works. `FBSession.activeSession` has changed to `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]`.

I however can't find the latest version of **closeAndClearTokenInformation** that works with the latest version. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
FBSDKLoginManager *logMeOut = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[logMeOut logOut];
```

or

```
[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];
```

to logout

Then when you login again, make sure to set:

```
login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
```

Like so:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_friends"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         etc...
}];
```

I found some info in the docs saying FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb can be used for "kiosk" apps; which I guess are apps designed to have more than one person log into them routinely.

One thing to note, this login method creates a modal UIWebView which is set up for portrait mode.  I'm not sure if its possible to change this yet.

Comment: Why would you include `login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;` ?

Comment: as a note the first option works without the need for `login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;` . I think you have setup the SDK wrong if you need to use this additional line.

Comment: the reason for `login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;` is that when you use Browser mode, the session is shared with safari's session and you never get logged out until user logs out from safari. but if you use web mode, you will be successfully logged out.

Comment: I emphasize on `login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;` to not share token with Safari app. Keep the token local to your app.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 2+ **Simple Solution**

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
```

Swift 5+ **Simple Solution**

```
LoginManager().logOut()
```

Comment: `LoginManager().logOut()` for latest swift Facebook Lib

Comment: @VinodSobale no

Answer (score 0):

In swift you may want to do the following for close the session entirely:

```
import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin

//...

//in your method:

let fbLoginManager = LoginManager()
fbLoginManager.logOut()
AccessToken.current = nil
UserProfile.current = nil
```