# Login and Logout with Facebook account

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I want to add login with Facebook account to my IOS app. I tried installing FacebookCore pod and FacebookLogin pod. My login action was successful but when I try to logout then login again, browser used the previous logged in account. Here is my code for login and logout action:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile ])
    loginButton.center = view.center
    //adding it to view
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginButton.delegate = self
}

func loginButtonDidCompleteLogin(_ loginButton: LoginButton, result: LoginResult) {
    print("logged in")
    self.loginButtonClicked()
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: LoginButton) {
    print("logged out")
    AccessToken.current = nil
    UserProfile.current = nil
    FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
}

//when login button clicked
func loginButtonClicked() {
    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.loginBehavior = .web
    loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [.publicProfile], viewController: self, completion: {loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print("loginnnnnn errrooorrr",error)
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login.")
            case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                self.getFBUserData()
        }
    })
}

//function is fetching the user data
func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                self.dict = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                self.isLogin = true
                print(result!)
                print(self.dict)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

How to login with another account?

Comment: I'm certain you've already looked at this [very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421659/reset-facebook-token-reference-facebook-sdk-4-0), which seems to indicate all you need to do is call `logOut`.  What I don't understand is why some of your code says `FBSDKAccessToken` in one function and `AccessToken` in a different function.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann i change every FBSDKAccessToken to AccessToken , i try all this link, but after logout i can enter new username password , i get this text in web : You previously logged in to LoginSampleTaban with Facebook. Would you like to continue?

Comment: That's a problem in FacebookSDK I think, you have to logout the user from facebook page in safari yourself.

Comment: You are only allowed to have one account. Why do you need to login using a different account?

Comment: @Mina i think safari save user login data. how can solve this?

Comment: @WizKid if user logout from app and want to login again with another account there is a problem with previous account

Comment: well, I had the same problem, each time that I wanted to login with a new user to test the app, I had to open facebook via safari and logout manually from facebook page then deleted the app from device or simulator and run again, that was the only way that I could login with different user, and there is also some complexity when you've already installed the facebook app.
you should logout the app as well, and also check the facebook account in settings of the device or simulator.

Comment: @Mina Well, this is not a solution that should be considered for the user, there must be a solution that may not hold the login information

Comment: as @WizKid said, it has considered that each user has only one facebook account, and the mentioned problem only happens when you are in developing test mode, not when you are a real final user.

Comment: @Mina oh, sorry i got it. thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, I was receiving

> you previously logged in to [app name] with Facebook. Would you like
>   to continue?

every time I wanted to log in into my app even after logout.

I solved it by using of Facebook native app (ver. 177).
You can 'log out' from your app here:

Menu Tab -> Settings -> 'Apps and Websites' -> 'Logged in with Facebook' -> Active -> select app -> tap Remove